# HTML and CSS <li> alignment in CSS

Tags: html, css, html-lists

so I am working on a project that is almost done, but I am trying to fix a problem that I have been having with `<li>`. I have a `<ol><li>` for my aside, and I have a `<ul>` of some text (I only need a few bullet points).
There is a constraint that ALL CSS must be external, which is the reason I don't know how to fix it.

The first Picture shows the entire page.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqe5u.png
The last picture shows the  that I am trying to move up and and align vertically without messing up the alignment of the text in the aside
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyIcI.png

Any help is greatly appreciated, and if more information is needed, I am happy to send more. Thanks in advance!!

```css
/* Assignment notes
            -Contains <main> element and is styled with at least 2 declarations
   -Contains <header> element and is styled with at least 2 declarations
   -Contains <nav> element and is styled with at least 2 declarations
   -Contains <footer> element and is styled with at least 2 declarations
   -Has a <meta> viewport
   -Font Family is declared in Body selector
   -Font Size is declared in Body Selector
   -Color properties and values are declared in Body selector
   -Padding and Margin are declared in <img>
   -Boarder Properties are declared in Content ID
   -Links are formated using Pseudo Seletors
   -Text Declaration is used to show Links
   -All CSS is external
   -Checked in Validator
*/
body {
    background: #98bfcd;
    border: 5px outset #fff;
 width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #00c;
    width: 461px;
}

aside {
    text-align: center;
    height: 500px;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-family: arial;
}

img{
 float: right;
 
}

h2 {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: Arial;
}

li a{
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

footer{
 float: center;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 2px;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

#content {
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bruesch- LP3 Advanced Home Page</title>
    <link href="HomeStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
</head>

<!-- Assignment notes
            -Contains <main> element and is styled with at least 2 declarations
            -Contains <header> element and is styled with at least 2 declarations
            -Contains <nav> element and is styled with at least 2 declarations
            -Contains <footer> element and is styled with at least 2 declarations
            -Has a <meta> viewport
            -Font Family is declared in Body selector
            -Font Size is declared in Body Selector
            -Color properties and values are declared in Body selector
            -Padding and Margin are declared in <img>
            -Boarder Properties are declared in Content ID
            -Links are formated using Pseudo Seletors
            -Text Declaration is used to show Links
            -All CSS is external
            -Checked in Validator
    -->


<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Test</h1><img alt="Crane Lifting HTML Text" height="302" src=
        "html5.jpg" width="400">
    </header>
    <div id="page-wrap">
        <aside>
            <nav>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <p><a href="#">Home</a></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p><a href="#" target="_blank">Webography</a></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p><a href="#" target="_blank">Resume</a></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p><a href="#" target="_blank">XML Demo</a></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p><a href="#" target="_blank">Contact</a></p>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </nav>
        </aside>
    </div>
    <h2>The Perks of HTML and CSS</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>asd</li>
        <li>asd</li>
        <li>asd</li>
    </ul>

<footer><a href="#top">Go to top</a></footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so you want move them to one line and make them look good?

Comment: I'm trying to get the part that says "The Perks Of HTML" to line up right under the <aside> and the <ul> (the one right under "The Perks Of HTML") to be vertical and not horizontal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CSS, You have made a small mistake for the properties of `<li>` element 
This is what you have given

```
li{
float: left;
}
```

This is changing your menu perfectly. But it is also effecting the list elements in the bottom. You can consider giving like below.

```
li a{
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the HTML to:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Bruesch- LP3 Advanced Home Page</title>
            <link href="HomeStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
        </head>

<!-- Assignment notes
            -Contains <main> element and is styled with at least 2 declarations
            -Contains <header> element and is styled with at least 2 declarations
            -Contains <nav> element and is styled with at least 2 declarations
            -Contains <footer> element and is styled with at least 2 declarations
            -Has a <meta> viewport
            -Font Family is declared in Body selector
            -Font Size is declared in Body Selector
            -Color properties and values are declared in Body selector
            -Padding and Margin are declared in <img>
            -Boarder Properties are declared in Content ID
            -Links are formated using Pseudo Seletors
            -Text Declaration is used to show Links
            -All CSS is external
            -Checked in Validator -->
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Test</h1><img alt="Crane Lifting HTML Text" height="302" src=
            "html5.jpg" width="400">
        </header>
        <div id="page-wrap">
            <aside>
                <nav>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <p><a href="#">Home</a></p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p><a href="#" target="_blank">Webography</a></p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p><a href="#" target="_blank">Resume</a></p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p><a href="#" target="_blank">XML Demo</a></p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p><a href="#" target="_blank">Contact</a></p>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </nav>
                <h2>The Perks of HTML and CSS</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>asd</li>
            <li>asd</li>
            <li>asd</li>
        </ul>
            </aside>
        </div>


    <footer><a href="#top">Go to top</a></footer>

    </body>
    </html>
```

And the style to:

```
/* Assignment notes
            -Contains <main> element and is styled with at least 2 declarations
            -Contains <header> element and is styled with at least 2 declarations
            -Contains <nav> element and is styled with at least 2 declarations
            -Contains <footer> element and is styled with at least 2 declarations
            -Has a <meta> viewport
            -Font Family is declared in Body selector
            -Font Size is declared in Body Selector
            -Color properties and values are declared in Body selector
            -Padding and Margin are declared in <img>
            -Boarder Properties are declared in Content ID
            -Links are formated using Pseudo Seletors
            -Text Declaration is used to show Links
            -All CSS is external
            -Checked in Validator
*/
body {
    background: #98bfcd;
    border: 5px outset #fff;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #00c;
    width: 461px;
}

aside {
    text-align: center;
    height: 500px;
}

nav li {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

li{
    text-align: left;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-family: arial;
}

img{
    float: right;

}

h2 {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: Arial;
}

li a{
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

footer{
    float: center;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 2px;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

#content {
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly,

To make `<ul>` (the one right under "The Perks Of HTML") to be vertical, you need to change css that

```
li {float: left;}
```

to

```
aside li {float: left;}
```

JSfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dhananjaymane11/k4L74rp9/2/

Answer (score -2):

I believe that adding a line break to each element of the list would work, like:

```html
<h2>The Perks of HTML and CSS</h2>
 <ul>
  <li>asd</li><br>
  <li>asd</li><br>
  <li>asd</li><br>
 </ul>
```

would work in creating a vertical alignment

Comment: Invalid code, can't have any other element than `li` as a direct child of `ul`

Comment: I have actually tested out doing such a thing with all his CSS and other HTML, and it just separates them, and aligns them vertically. Unless my browser reads HTML and CSS differently, I believe that simply adding line breaks would fix the problem.

Comment: Because it work does not mean it is valid ... browsers tries to fix errors as good as they can, hence invalid code sometimes work

Comment: Ah, you can tell I don't always do things the "proper" way. In any case, proper or not, it at least fixes the vertical alignment issue and stops the text from overlapping.

Comment: No, I don't say you do that, I say "non proper code" _can_ give the desired result.